# How to handle cutout area by compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-windowmanager, android-cutout

I'm a Android development beginner .
How to handle cutout area by compose?
As far as I know...
WindowManager doesn't provide information about cutout area.
and LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode can be set in xml file.
I ask for your advice, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Compose **1.2.*** you can get it like this:

```
// get value:
WindowInsets.displayCutout

// apply padding modifier:
Modifier.displayCutoutPadding()
```

In earlier versions you can use [Accompanist Insets](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#original-docs) library:

```
// get value:
LocalWindowInsets.current.displayCutout

// apply padding modifier:
Modifier.cutoutPadding()
```